# Resize background-image to fill the page height-wise, but allow elements on either side

Tags: html, css, xhtml, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm having a lot of issues trying to do this, and I'm now wondering if it's even possible in css. (Maybe I will need to find some other way using PHP, Flash or Javascript!)

Basically, I have 3 images. Each are 1920x1200 (x*y) in size. When placed from left-to-right they form an image of a landscape. I want to create a webpage in which you scroll horizontally to see each part of the site with the 3 images being the background-images of the div elements and touching each other on either side. The scrolling was going to be handled with [this](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable.html) (which is also the reason why .items needed to be position: absolute.) For the most part, I've been able to create this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item" id="item1"><a name="item1"></a>
         text
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="item2"><a name="item2"></a>
         more text
    </div>

    <div class="item" id="item3"><a name="item3"></a>
         even more text
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#item1, #item2, #item3 { 
    float: left;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1200px;
}
#item1 {
    background: #ffffff url(../../images/main/1.jpg);
}
#item2 {
    background: #ffffff url(../../images/main/2.jpg);
}
#item3 {
    background: #ffffff url(../../images/main/3.jpg);
}
/* our additional wrapper element for the items */ 
.items { 
    width: 5790px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

However, the issue that I have is that I need to make this work for multiple screen sizes and resolutions. What I would like to be able to do, is to make the height of each of the #itemn to be 100% of the visible page, but I am unable to do so without stopping the div elements from appearing left-right. Often it causes them to appear on top of each other.

I tried following out the instructions [here](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ImageToBackgroundImage/) and using an img. But, by setting the position to fixed or absolute I caused the images inside the div elements which I had previously floated left to appear on top of each other.

Just to be clear, the effect that I am going for is like [this sites'](http://www.webtalents.pl/), but I *need* the background image to be resized height-wise to fit the page, otherwise it will look bad on different resolutions from my machine. I can provide more explanation if needs be, but I think I've summed up the problem pretty well. Is it possible to fix this in any way - perhaps using Javascript, PHP, or Flash?

**EDIT**

I just found that there is a CSS3 property that does exactly what I need (background-size), but it's not implemented in most browsers...
A hack would be to use -moz-border-image and then use php to place the correct height and width px into the css. I do not want to do that!

Comment: So you want the height to be 100%, but you don't want the tiling to show? That means you'll have to stretch the image if, say, the user has a browser set to 900px by 900px...That'll be uglier than showing part of the next image...

Comment: There won't be any tiling horizontally since the images form a large landscape when placed alongside eachother. 

The issue is that currently on low resolutions: the bottom of the image gets cut off (which looks bad, because it's a landscape and you end up only seeing the sky.) On high resolutions the image either ends abruptly with an ugly line or tiles.

Comment: See this site for an example of what I want to achieve: http://www.webtalents.pl/

They have an easier job, however, since they have images that overlap and a background that tiles, while I just have a large image that I want to use for each screen.

Comment: Aha. I see. The problem you'll have with this is if a user changes the height of their browser, the images would get smaller. And that would probably mess up your other `<div>`'s placement..

Comment: You could probably add some javascript to change the placement and sizing of all the elements `onresize`. But that might make the site very sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use photoshop to combine your three images into one large image? If you do the technique shown on CSS tricks should work.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, due to the jquery plugin I use to automatically scroll the page not working when I do this.

Comment: What jquery plugin specifically are you trying to use?